# get first element of a list using regex

Tags: python, regex

I have a list in the following format:

```
s = "['abc', 'xxx', '3c2', '111112', 'x']"
```

How would I get the element "1" -- the item that comes after the `[` but before the `,`. So far I had:

```
re.search(r'[.+,',s)
```

But it is too 'greedy'. What would be the correct regex here?

Comment: @chrisz the first element could be anything -- it's just a list element, it could be "123adi j3o",

Comment: Just add `?` to make it non-greedy: `[(.+?),`

Comment: @georg please see updated question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your list appears to be valid python, so regex is not an option (regexes cannot reliably parse programming languages). Consider [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) instead:

```
>>> s = "['abc', 'xxx', '3c2', '111112', 'x']"
>>> import ast
>>> ast.literal_eval(s)[0]
'abc'
```

If you insist of using regexes, you'll have to create a fairy complex expression to match python literals. A naive example, that only handles single-quoted strings, would be:

```
>>> s = "['abc', 'xxx', '3c2', '111112', 'x']"
>>> import re
>>> str_re = r"'(\\.|[^'])*'"
>>> re.search(str_re, s).group(1)
'abc'
```

Quite obviously, adding double-quoted, multi-quoted, raw- and byte-strings, and eventually a variety of number formats to this would be a tedious and totally pointless job ;)

Answer (score 1):

Using regex [`'[^,]+'`](https://regex101.com/r/Flyxj6/4) or if you want to capture value inside single quotes use capturing group [`'([^,]+)'`](https://regex101.com/r/Flyxj6/5) and `re.search().group(1)`.

```
re.search(r"'[^,]+'",s).group()
```

Output:

```
'abc'
```

Comment: How about `'I hate \'quotes\'...'` ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
import re
s = "['abc', 'xxx', '3c2', '111112', 'x']"
m = next(re.finditer(r"'([^']+)'", s))

print(m.group())
```